# How to say "as (it) is"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Something like: "keep the situation as is".

I guess there might be many options to convey the required meaning, however, I also assume there is a phrase that is more commonly used?

I was thinking of "sicut est" or "ut est", but I'm not sure as the usage of "est" is so appropriate here. maybe better "sicut id est".

It might also be usful to contrast the phrase *"as is"* with the phrase *"like that"* which, to my understating of English, don't have the same meaning. *"like that"* implies comparison to something else, where *"as is"* is "comparison" of something to itself - to it's own current state.

Comment: I can think of a lot of ways of saying this that might be appropriate.  Obviously "sicut est" follows the wording of a very common prayer.  It might be interesting to find the Latin original for the supposed rule used by Henry II to resolve land disputes "Let it be as it was on the day of my grandfather's death."  I haven't been able to find it in Latin.  The book I saw the translation in suggested the original might be in Glanvill.  If you have access to a good library that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

How about "status quo"? Giving:

"tene rem statu quo est" = "hold (keep = tene--imperative singular of "teneo") the matter (whatever it is; accusative direct-object, "rem") in the condition/ position/ circumstance/ state (ablative, "statu") in which (ablative, "quo") it is (est).

Attestations of the use of "status quo" can be found at "glosbe.com/la/en/status quo".